# Get user name from application string

Tags: c#, string, silverlight

I have created a Silverlight business application, that require the user to login, and once they have, their user name is presented in the login status.

Located in the ApplicationStrings.resx is the following-

```
<data name="WelcomeMessage" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Welcome {0}</value>
  <comment>{0} = User.DisplayName property</comment>
</data>
```

I am trying to get the user name of whoever has logged in from this, I have tried-

```
string userName = System.Convert.ToString(ApplicationStrings.WelcomeMessage);
```

However this brings the string backs as `Welcome {0}`.

Whereas what I actually need is the value of `User.DisplayName property`.

How can I get to that value?

Comment: Using the `User` object?

Comment: Im not sure, but for instance once I have logged in, the value would be "Welcome John Smith" where John Smith is the User.DisplayName property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string.Format at the place where you retrieve the welcome message.

```
string userName = string.Format(ApplicationStrings.WelcomeMessage, WebContext.Current.User.DisplayName);
```

Comment: @SLaks that is true, copying and pasting too much :-)

Answer (score 2):

I did it by -

```
string userName = WebContext.Current.User.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Simon's answer is the same thing but more appropriate as it includes the formatting you requested as well. Make sure you give him credit for it as *the first correct answer.*

Comment: Simons answer did not work as 'User' did not exist in the current context.

Comment: That just means you were missing a `using` statement in your app... certainly not Simon's fault you missed that. I have added the explicit namespace to his answer.

Comment: @HiTechMagic thanks for editing my answer, and the accepted answer request.

Comment: @Simon: Fair is fair. I have plenty of unaccepted correct/early answers of my own :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `string.Format` for `{0}` recognition.